Does the workload for pthreads really need to be in ms for pthreads to be beneficial?
I am trying to measure at which workloads' pthreads become useful. So far, I found that workloads need to take around ~3ms for pthreads to contribute positively to the overall progress  (on an Alderlake test system).
Is this the correct order of magnitude?
The benchmarking output is below:
BM_dispatch<dispatch>/16/process_time/real_time                1.37 ms         1.37 ms          513
BM_dispatch<dispatch>/32/process_time/real_time                2.75 ms         2.75 ms          252
BM_dispatch<dispatch>/48/process_time/real_time                4.15 ms         4.15 ms          169
BM_dispatch<dispatch>/64/process_time/real_time                5.52 ms         5.52 ms          126
BM_dispatch<dispatch>/80/process_time/real_time                6.89 ms         6.89 ms          101
BM_dispatch<dispatch>/96/process_time/real_time                8.26 ms         8.26 ms           84
BM_dispatch<dispatch>/112/process_time/real_time               9.62 ms         9.62 ms           72

BM_dispatch<dispatch_pthread>/16/process_time/real_time        2.16 ms         4.18 ms          359
BM_dispatch<dispatch_pthread>/32/process_time/real_time        3.76 ms         7.38 ms          200
BM_dispatch<dispatch_pthread>/48/process_time/real_time        3.67 ms         7.18 ms          150
BM_dispatch<dispatch_pthread>/64/process_time/real_time        4.30 ms         8.44 ms          163
BM_dispatch<dispatch_pthread>/80/process_time/real_time        4.38 ms         8.60 ms          176
BM_dispatch<dispatch_pthread>/96/process_time/real_time        4.93 ms         9.69 ms          146
BM_dispatch<dispatch_pthread>/112/process_time/real_time       5.31 ms         10.5 ms          126

I benchmark two functions dispatch and dispatch_pthread under different workload sizes. The function do the same total work, but dispatch_pthreads divides the work among two threads. When the runtime is about ~1 ms, pthreads are not beneficial. Around a workload of ~8ms, two pthreads are about twice as fast as a single thread.
The full program is below:
void find_max(const float* in, size_t eles, float* out) {
    float max{0};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < eles; ++i) {
        if (in[i] > max) max = in[i];
    }
    *out = max;
}

float dispatch(const float* inp, size_t rows, size_t cols, float* out) {
    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        find_max(inp + row * cols, cols, out + row);
    }
}

struct pthreadpool_context {
    const float* inp;
    size_t rows;
    size_t cols;
    float* out;
};

void* work(void* ctx) {
    const pthreadpool_context* context = (pthreadpool_context*)ctx;
    dispatch(context->inp, context->rows, context->cols, context->out);
    return NULL;
}

float dispatch_pthread(const float* inp, size_t rows, size_t cols, float* out) {
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    size_t rows_per_thread = rows / 2;
    const pthreadpool_context context1 = {inp, rows_per_thread, cols, out};
    const pthreadpool_context context2 = {inp + rows_per_thread * cols,
                                          rows_per_thread, cols,
                                          out + rows_per_thread};
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, work, (void*)&context1);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, work, (void*)&context2);
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
}


template <auto F>
void BM_dispatch(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::random_device rnd_device;
    std::mt19937 mersenne_engine{rnd_device()};
    std::normal_distribution<float> dist{0, 1};
    auto gen = [&]() { return dist(mersenne_engine); };
    const size_t cols = 1024 * state.range(0);
    constexpr size_t rows = 100;
    std::vector<float> inp(rows * cols);
    std::generate(inp.begin(), inp.end(), gen);
    std::vector<float> out(rows);
    for (auto _ : state) {
        F(inp.data(), rows, cols, out.data());
    }
}

BENCHMARK(BM_dispatch<dispatch>)
    ->DenseRange(16, 112, 16)
    ->MeasureProcessCPUTime()
    ->UseRealTime()
    ->Unit(benchmark::kMillisecond);
BENCHMARK(BM_dispatch<dispatch_pthread>)
    ->DenseRange(16, 112, 16)
    ->MeasureProcessCPUTime()
    ->UseRealTime()
    ->Unit(benchmark::kMillisecond);
BENCHMARK_MAIN();

The program gets compiled with O2 optimization with gcc 13.2.0 on Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 5.15.

A side note (not related to performabce): since you tagged C++: why do you not use std::threads ?

... or standard execution policies: std::max_element(std::execution::par, ...

sorry, good point. I wanted to use low level threading primitives to see their scaling behaviour, but you are right that the code is a mixture of both c and c++.

@fabian std::thread is a pretty low level primitive. It adds syntactic sugar on top of the platform specific API, but other than that, it does the same thing.

just if its of interest: I tried with std::thread and the runtime is very close to pthreads. Thanks for the suggestion.

@fabian You could then also try using std::max_element with std::execution::par or std::execution::par_unseq to see if the built-in thread pool does a better job.

If you want to accelerate microsecond scale operations, there's SIMD, but it isn't suitable for all workloads, or you can have already created threads busy waiting for work rather than creating and joining threads. If my memory serves me correctly, the time to release the locks etc is of the order of 1 us, so orders of magnitude faster than creating and joining threads.

Thanks a lot, @SimonGoater. The workload above just serves a simple dummy that I can try on different archs, so I want to avoid SIMD for this demo. The suggestion to work with already launched threads is very interesting, I will try to check that!

Spawning thread frequently is rather slow and not efficient anyway. You should really avoid that for sake of performance and also to reduce the pressure on the OS resources. A usual way to parallelise codes is to spawn a pool of worker threads and then submit tasks to them (typically 1 task per worker for parallel loops). Note that you should not measure the time of the pool creation in benchmarks since it is rarely a bottleneck in real-world application lasting >1 second (assuming the pool is often reused).

Doing this in pthreads is cumbersome. It is a bit easier with C++ threads but still not really trivial. You can use OpenMP (included in all mainstream compilers) to do that very easily : #pragma omp parallel for for embarrassingly parallel loops or #pragma omp parallel for reduction(...) for reductions. OpenMP creates a pool of thread equal to the number of thread supported by the machine, and recycle them as much as possible. Since many computing libraries already use/support it (eg. Eigen, OpenBLAS, OpenCV), the incremental overhead of creating OpenMP threads is basically null.

(note though that the number of thread of the section should stay the same, otherwise an implementation is free to respawn all the threads which can be expensive -- also note that creating thread in a loop can be inefficient on some platform like many-core ones and in this case it can be more efficient to use a spawning tree which is even harder to implement, not to mention it is simple to bind threads to core with OpenMP and care about NUMA platforms while it is not simple with pthreads nor C++ threads -- this is why OpenMP is a standard for multithreading on all modern HPC platforms)

Frame challenge: if you have a sub-millisecond task, how important is it, really, to make it go faster?  From this perspective, the workload probably needs to be much more than ms for the added complexity attending multithreading to be worthwhile, regardless of the speedup it provides.

The pthread of the GLIBC under Linux maintains a pool of stacks. This pool is empty at process startup. When threads are created and then terminated, the stacks are not freed but kept in the pool to be reused by subsequent threads. The default stack size is 8 MB of virtual memory by default and the size of the pool is 40 MB. This means that by default, up to 5 stacks can be cached for reuse.
As a consequence, the first two threads creation is slower as the stacks are not allocated yet. But for the subsequent ones, this is faster because the stacks are picked from the pool. But the thread creation is not only a stack allocation but also many other things like TLS initialization, guard page setting (for stack overflow detection)...
Hence, it is better to put the thread creation outside of the benchmark measurement. That is to say, as noticed in the comments, the worker threads should be created first.
Here is the pthread code snippet concerning the allocation of the stacks from the internal pool:
/* Maximum size in kB of cache.  */
static size_t stack_cache_maxsize = 40 * 1024 * 1024; /* 40MiBi by default.  */
[...]
/* Get a stack frame from the cache.  We have to match by size since
   some blocks might be too small or far too large.  */
static struct pthread *
get_cached_stack (size_t *sizep, void **memp)
{
  size_t size = *sizep;
  struct pthread *result = NULL;
  list_t *entry;

  lll_lock (stack_cache_lock, LLL_PRIVATE);

  /* Search the cache for a matching entry.  We search for the
     smallest stack which has at least the required size.  Note that
     in normal situations the size of all allocated stacks is the
     same.  As the very least there are only a few different sizes.
     Therefore this loop will exit early most of the time with an
     exact match.  */
  list_for_each (entry, &stack_cache)
    {
      struct pthread *curr;
[...]


Interesting.  But allocating (and page-faulting) a thread stack is only a small part of creating a new thread.  There's also a lot of work inside the kernel to allocate a new task.  Putting thread creation outside a benchmark only makes sense if your real use-case uses a thread pool (reusing whole threads, not just their stack allocations), which, as comments under the question point out, might be something the OP didn't know.

Thanks for the detailed answer. I accept it (also to close the thread) but want to express my gratitude to Simon Goater and Jerome Richard as they already honed in on the original problem.

Thanks for all the comments and answers. The main problem of the original code is thread creation within benchmark timing.
To provide a comprehensive answer, the benchmark results with a threadpool follow.
I created a threadpool along the lines of Thread pooling in C++11. With two threads, the latency of the entire operation is indeed halved compared to the single-threaded code, already for workloads measured in microseconds.
The full timings are:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                                                 Time             CPU   Iterations
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BM_dispatch<dispatch>/4/process_time/real_time        0.341 ms        0.341 ms         2062
BM_dispatch<dispatch>/8/process_time/real_time        0.691 ms        0.691 ms         1007
BM_dispatch<dispatch>/12/process_time/real_time        1.04 ms         1.04 ms          672
BM_dispatch<dispatch>/16/process_time/real_time        1.39 ms         1.39 ms          500
BM_dispatch<dispatch>/20/process_time/real_time        1.75 ms         1.75 ms          399
BM_dispatch<dispatch>/24/process_time/real_time        2.11 ms         2.11 ms          331
BM_dispatch<dispatch>/28/process_time/real_time        2.48 ms         2.48 ms          284
BM_dispatch<dispatch>/32/process_time/real_time        2.84 ms         2.84 ms          246

BM_dispatch_threadpool/4/process_time/real_time       0.176 ms        0.353 ms         3933
BM_dispatch_threadpool/8/process_time/real_time       0.356 ms        0.717 ms         1947
BM_dispatch_threadpool/12/process_time/real_time      0.522 ms         1.05 ms         1308
BM_dispatch_threadpool/16/process_time/real_time      0.713 ms         1.43 ms         1000
BM_dispatch_threadpool/20/process_time/real_time      0.880 ms         1.77 ms          795
BM_dispatch_threadpool/24/process_time/real_time       1.04 ms         2.10 ms          650
BM_dispatch_threadpool/28/process_time/real_time       1.22 ms         2.45 ms          577
BM_dispatch_threadpool/32/process_time/real_time       1.40 ms         2.82 ms          504

BM_dispatch<dispatch> measures single threaded-code as above. BM_dispatch_threadpool measures latencies when the work is passed to a already created threadpool with two threads.
